# How does Vertex AI AutoML encode categorical variables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, categorical-data, google-cloud-automl

How does Vertex AI AutoML handle categorical variables? I'm particularly interested in high cardinality categorical variables.

Relevant documentation from Google:

[https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/data-types-tabular#categorical-transf](https://stackoverflow.com)

With this cryptic line:

**Convert the category name to a dictionary lookup index and generate an embedding for each index.
**

But they don't discuss how the embedding is generated? One-hot encoding? Target encoding? Other?

I have searched and read other documentation, but I haven't found an answer. I do know that BQML used to only use one-hot encoding